# How to find a dom element inside another dom element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html returned to me in an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/get-html',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(html) {
        html = $(html);
        ....
```

In the success method I wish to find the img tag inside the container div in the html var and change it's alt tag.

If I do:

```
html.find('img').attr('alt', 'new alt');
```

We update the alts on all the images. How can I specify just the alt for the container div? I've tried this:

```
html.find('.container img').attr('alt', 'new alt');
```

But it doesnt work.

FYI here's an example of the HTML returned in the ajax call:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="" alt="PLEASE CHANGE THIS ALT">
</div>
<img src="" alt="LEAVE MY ALT ALONE">
<img src="" alt="LEAVE MY ALT ALONE">
```

Comment: Yes 100% sure, the example does not work.

Comment: The `.container` is the wrapper, not child of `html`. So use `html.filter('.container').find('img')`

Comment: eisbehr this does not work.

Comment: Ohh, @A.Wolff is correct, I was wrong ...

Comment: A. Wolff - you are correct, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try This -

```js
var html = '<div class="container"><img src="" alt="PLEASE CHANGE THIS ALT"/></div><img src="" alt="LEAVE MY ALT ALONE"/><img src="" alt="LEAVE MY ALT ALONE"/>';

//Print Your html Code before changing alt attr.
$('body').append(html);
$('body').append('<hr/>');

html = $(html);

//Check img inside .div and change attr
html.children('.container img').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('alt', 'new alt');
  //Log changed attr
  console.log($(this).attr('alt'));
});
//Print Your html Code after changing alt attr.
$('body').append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dt22qkhu/1/)